# tkinter create a loop in a frame

Tags: python-3.x, loops, tkinter, frame

I'm building a program in Python/tkinter using frames and want to have the time and other things update? 
Below is part of a program. The first def is a loop and is displaying in its own window. I want this data to be displayed in the second `'HomePage'` frame. Is this possible?

**Hi Furas, I don't have a root.mainloop() - and even if I did how on earth would I get things like the clock to update?**

http://pastebin.com/LrNi6tjg

```
def iSatMainLoop():  # Main program loop, runs regularly by calling itself using after.
    current_time = str(datetime.utcnow())

    label = Label(root, bd="0", text="Time: %s" % current_time[1:19]) #Insert time here!
    label.grid(row=1, columnspan=1, column=2)
    "Time: %s" % current_time[1:19]

    global NextLogTime;

    curDateTime = datetime.utcnow()

    if curDateTime >= NextLogTime:
        NextLogTime += timedelta(seconds=interval)
        print("test text")

    if  Yellow_Alert:
        if YellowCounter:
            Yellow1()
    else:
        if YellowCounter:
            Green1()
    if  Orange_Alert:
         if OrangeCounter:
            Orange2()
    else:
         if OrangeCounter:
            Green2()            
    if Red_Alert:
         if RedCounter:
            Red3()
    else:
         if RedCounter:
            Green3()

    root.after(1000, iSatMainLoop)

class HomePage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) #, text='Home page', font=Roboto_Normal_Font)

        current_time = str(datetime.utcnow())
        label = Label(self, bd="0", text="Time: %s" % current_time[1:19]) #Insert time here!
        label.grid(row=1, columnspan=1, column=2)
        "Time: %s" % current_time[1:19]

        robototimelabel=tk.Label(self, text = strftime('Time: '+'%Y-%m-%d'+' '+'%H:%M:%S'),
                             font=Roboto_Normal_Large_Font, background= '#0000FF', foreground= '#FFFFFF')
        robototimelabel.place(x=200, y=10)

        robotostatuslabel=tk.Label(self, text = 'Status:',
                             font=Roboto_Normal_Large_Font, background= '#0000FF', foreground= '#FFFFFF')
        robotostatuslabel.place(x=500, y=10)

        severefaultstatuslabel=tk.Label(self,
                             font=Modern_Pictograms_Font, text = 'l', background= '#0000FF', foreground= '#FFFFFF')
                            #font=('modernpics.ttf', 12), text = 'l', background= '#0000FF', foreground= '#FFFFFF')                                    

        severefaultstatuslabel.place(x=600, y=10)

        sysconfigbutton=tk.Button(self, text= 'System\nConfiguration', font=Roboto_Normal_Font,        
                                  command=lambda: controller.show_frame(SystemConfigurationPage),
                                  height=2, width=15)
        sysconfigbutton.place(x=20, y=80)

        sysstatbutton=tk.Button(self, text= 'System Status', font=Roboto_Normal_Font,
                                command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StatusPage),
                                height=2, width=15)
        sysstatbutton.place(x=20, y=180)

        TLEmenubutton=tk.Button(self, text= 'TLE Menu', font=Roboto_Normal_Font,
                                 command=lambda: controller.show_frame(TLEMenuPage),
                                height=2, width=15)
        TLEmenubutton.place(x=20, y=280)

        resetgraphbutton=tk.Button(self, text= 'Reset Graph', font=Roboto_Normal_Font,
                                   height=2, width=15)
        resetgraphbutton.place(x=20, y=380)

        graphcanvas=tk.Canvas(self, height=340, width=550)

        graphcanvas.place(x=200, y=80)`
```

Comment: edit question and use button `{}` to correctly format code in SO.

Comment: use class instance instead of `root` in  `Label(root)` to display time in different window.

Comment: instead of creating new `Label` with time you should change text in existing label - now you have many labels (one above another) in the same cell.

Comment: different examples [how to use `after` to display time](https://github.com/furas/my-python-codes/tree/master/tkinter/timer-using-after) - ie. using functions, classes and creating own widget.

Comment: better use `root.mainloop()` and you will need no `mainloop()` in any other frame`